# Adding Random Characters Between Characters in a String (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to add random letters after each letter in a given range, but they aren't in complete randomness.

```
def add_letters(org,num):
    new_word = ''
    for i in org:
        randomLetter = random.choice(string.ascii_letters) * num
        new_word += i
        new_word += randomLetter
    return new_word

original = 'Hello!'
for num in range(1,5):
    #scramble the word using 'num' extra characters
    scrambled = add_letters(original,num)
    #output
    print("Adding",num,'random characters to',original,'->',scrambled)
```

some of the results will have the same letter repeating multiple times like "HAAAAeiiiilzzzzlBBBBoSSSS!jjjj". Instead, they should be random.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your *question*? What happens when you run your code, and how is that different from what you want to happen? Are you saying "some of my results *do* have repeating letters, and they *should not*"? Well, you *do* understand that when you randomly pick values with replacement, sometimes they will repeat, right? Like, if you draw a card from a deck, put it back, shuffle the deck and draw a card again, you *could draw the same card again*, you understand this, right?

Comment: Please read [ask] and try to communicate more clearly.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel my results are printing strings like HAAAAeiiiilzzzzlBBBBoSSSS!jjjj, which isn't my goal, because the "random" letters that are placed between each letter of "Hello!" are repeating. Instead, they should be random.

Comment: In your own words, when you write `random.choice(string.ascii_letters) * num`, what does that mean? (Hint: if you write `'a' * 5`, what does that mean? Now, if that `'a'` value *happened to be computed by* calling `random.choice`, should your answer to that question change? Why?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You used `*sum`, which only generate `randomLetter` once and repeat the result letter for `sum` times. It's not repeat the random generation. So the result repeated.
- It should be a `loop` or `list-comprehension` to generate mutiple `randomLetter`.

#### fixed code:

```
import random
import string
def add_letters(org,num):
    new_word = ''
    for i in org:
        randomLetter = "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(num))
        new_word += i
        new_word += randomLetter
    return new_word

original = 'Hello!'
for num in range(1,5):
    #scramble the word using 'num' extra characters
    scrambled = add_letters(original,num)
    #output
    print("Adding",num,'random characters to',original,'->',scrambled)
```

#### result:

```
Adding 1 random characters to Hello! -> HNemldlgos!z
Adding 2 random characters to Hello! -> HVTeGYlYLlxdonV!GM
Adding 3 random characters to Hello! -> HqjbeQyOlgfHlAwqoyCj!PRq
Adding 4 random characters to Hello! -> HyFoLeyHUzlExGelVLlAoOhyz!EuzW
```